# Java Swing : JPanel only shows up once JFrame is scaled

Tags: java, swing

I was working on a mini blackjack game and I ust got to the GUI and Im running into a small problem where I have 2 JPanels within a JFrame and only one would appear once I run the main method and a dot would appear over the area where I specified the location of the second panel . Once I scale the JFrame up or down or in any direction with the mouse , the JPanel appears at its correct location . Im kinda stumped on how to fix that problem , because  I tried a bunch of different things and couldn't figure it out. Any help is greatly appreciated. Here's the code:

```
<
```

`import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.FlowLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener; 

import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
import javax.swing.JFrame ; 
import javax.swing.JButton ;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel ;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.BoxLayout;


public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {


public GUI(){
    //Constructor for BlackJack 

    ///Frame/////////////////////////////////////////////
    super("BlackJack");  

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setBackground(Color.WHITE);
    setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
    setSize(1051,550);
    setResizable(true);
    GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
    GridBagConstraints gbc2 = new GridBagConstraints();
    gbc.insets = new Insets(10,10,10,10);
    gbc2.insets= new Insets(10,10,10,10);


    // Creating all the necessary panels.
    JPanel scores = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel dealer = new JPanel(); 
    JPanel player = new JPanel();
    JPanel bettingArea = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    JPanel messages = new JPanel();  
    messages.setLayout(new BoxLayout(messages,BoxLayout.PAGE_AXIS));



    //Adding the panels to the Frame.

    gbc2.anchor=GridBagConstraints.NORTHEAST;
    add(scores,gbc2);

    gbc2.anchor=GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_START;
    add(bettingArea,gbc2);

    gbc2.anchor=GridBagConstraints.LAST_LINE_END;
    add(messages,gbc2);

    // Setting borders for each Panel.
    scores.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 3));
    bettingArea.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.DARK_GRAY, 3));
    messages.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE, 3));

    ////////End of Frame/////////////////////////////////////////////////

    //score's Interface //////////////////////////////
    /////////////////////////////////////////////////

    JButton hit = new JButton("Hit");
    JButton check = new JButton("Check");
    JLabel plrScore = new JLabel("Player Score");
    JLabel dlrScore = new JLabel("Dealer Score");

    // Setting Different Border Colors for the Player and Dealer
    plrScore.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
    dlrScore.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLACK));

    // Setting up the GridBagConstraints.
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    scores.add(plrScore,gbc);

    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    scores.add(dlrScore,gbc);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    scores.add(hit,gbc);

    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    scores.add(check,gbc); 


    //bettingArea's Interface //////////////////////////
    ///////////////////////////////////////////////////
    JButton increaseBet = new JButton("Increase");
    JButton decreaseBet = new JButton("Decrease");
    JTextArea playerBet = new JTextArea("Player Bet");
    JTextArea playerCash = new JTextArea("Player Cash"); 

    // Setting Different Borders for the Objects
    playerBet.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder());
    playerCash.setBorder(BorderFactory.createRaisedSoftBevelBorder());


    // Setting up the GridBagConstraints.
    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    bettingArea.add(increaseBet,gbc);

    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=0;
    bettingArea.add(playerBet,gbc);

    gbc.gridx=0;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    bettingArea.add(decreaseBet,gbc);

    gbc.gridx=1;
    gbc.gridy=1;
    bettingArea.add(playerCash,gbc);

    ////messages Interface///////////////////// 

    JTextArea msg1 = new JTextArea("Message 1"); 
    JTextArea msg2 = new JTextArea("Message 2"); 
    JTextArea msg3 = new JTextArea("Message 3"); 
    JTextArea msg4 = new JTextArea("Message 4"); 

    messages.add(msg1); 
    messages.add(Box.createRigidArea( new Dimension(0,2)));
    messages.add(msg2);
    messages.add(Box.createRigidArea( new Dimension(0,2)));
    messages.add(msg3);
    messages.add(Box.createRigidArea( new Dimension(0,2)));
    messages.add(msg4);


    //Visibility of Panels & JFrame.
    scores.setVisible(true);
    bettingArea.setVisible(true);
    messages.setVisible(true);
    setVisible(true); 




}





public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}


// Main Method
public static void main ( String args[]){
    GUI game = new GUI();
}`

}

Comment: Call setVisible only after you have completed building the UI. Otherwise you'll need to call revalidate

Comment: Ahh of the JFrame....havent tried that. I tried putting the setVisible of the panels at the end but it didnt work. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

you need to remove the `setVisible(true);` from the `GUI()` constructor. Rather put it inside the `main()` function and `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` as follows:

```
public static void main ( String args[]){
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            new GUI().setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}
```

Swing gui update and rendering task should be performed in EDT(event dispatch thread). Above call do just that for us.

Comment: You don't "need" to remove it from the constructor, not saying it's not a bad idea, the OP just needs to make sure that they call it last. In fact, it would be better if the OP didn't extend directly from JFrame ;)

Comment: Ran into another problem regarding positioning . I can't seem to anchor my panels to the top right corner or bottom left corner using the GridBagConstraints...I edited the code as well

Comment: @user1810925, post another question depicting your problem. With layout, it is better if you attach a pic or link to a pic demonstrating your problem graphically. This is how the site works. [Read the about page](http://stackoverflow.com/about).